"module not found error" with twilio serverless deploy
I have been facing module not found error while trying to deploy my nodejs app using twilio serverless.
Here is my nodejs application folder structure:
functions
├── chunk_text.js
├── gpt_handler.js
├── hello-world.js
├── make_call.js
├── pre-scraping.js
├── private-message.js
├── read_scraped.js
├── respond.js
├── sms
│   └── reply.protected.js
├── transcribe.js
└── vector_db.js

My respond.js function looks like this:
   const axios = require('axios');
    const { getRelevantContext } = require('./vector_db');
    const { createGPT4Response } = require('./gpt_handler');
    
    // Define the main function for handling requests
   //...

The vector_db.js function looks like so:
const { Pinecone } = require('@pinecone-database/pinecone');
const { embedText } = require('./gpt_handler');

// Initialize Pinecone
//...
module.exports = { getRelevantContext };

I then tried to deploy my application using twilio serverless:
twilio serverless:deploy

And then run the app using
node functions/make_call.js

I then try to make a POST request to my application like so:
curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/make_call \
// -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
// -d '{"myNumber": "+mynumber"}'

This first makes a POST request to /transcribe that goes successfully. Next, a POST request is made to /respond that fails with the following log:
{
    "message": "Cannot find module './vector_db'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/handlers/ZN4b9ac101952f555dd0714e7598bece55.js\n- /var/task/node_modules/runtime-handler/index.js\n- /var/task/runtime-handler.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "name": "Error",
    "stack": "Error: Cannot find module './vector_db'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/handlers/ZN4b9ac101952f555dd0714e7598bece55.js\n- /var/task/node_modules/runtime-handler/index.js\n- /var/task/runtime-handler.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs\n    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1140:15)\n    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:27)\n    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)\n    at Module.twilioRequire [as require] (/var/task/node_modules/runtime-handler/src/dependency.js:28:21)\n    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:177:18)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/handlers/ZN4b9ac101952f555dd0714e7598bece55.js:2:32)\n    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1364:14)\n    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1422:10)\n    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:32)\n    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1019:12)"
}

I double checked to ensure that both vector_db and respond lies in the same function directory, as mentioned earlier. No spelling issues or case errors.

if you want to run your serverless locally you have to run the following command: twilio serverless:start and then you can test your endoint locally using Curl.
If you want to test your deployed serverless endpoint using Curl, you have to use the url of the serverless, not localhost.
